# VueX: how to load the data of a foreign key (microservice architecture)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, computed-properties

In my project I have the states `products` and `orders`. Each order contains the id of a product, or an array with product ids. They are coming from different APIs. (like MicroService Architekture)

The JSON structure of an order:

```
[
   {
      "orderId": 1,
      "productId": 360
   }
]
```

**order.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
  order: {}
})

export const getters = {
  order: state => state.allOrder,
}

export const mutations = {
  async setOrderById(state, order) {
     state.order = order;
  }

export const actions = {
  async setOrderById(state, orderId) {
    const order = await this.$axios.get(api + orderId);
    state.commit('setOrderById', client.data);
  }
```

The **product.js** has the same  structure, but with some different attributes like "title, name, price etc:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "title_de": "Example T-Shirt",
  "price": 550
}
```

Now, in my component I want to load the product properties of an order. What is the best practice to do it? It is kind of complicated, because in my components I am loading the data via the computed property. In the end, I would like something like this:

**OrderComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="currentOrder">
    {{ currentOrder.product.title }} <!-- UNDEFINED -->
    {{ currentOrder.product.price }} <!-- UNDEFINED -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: "OrderDetail",
  data() {
    return {
      orderId: this.$route.params.id,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      currentOrder: 'shop/orders/order'
    })
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('shop/orders/setOrderById', this.orderId)
  }
}
</script>
```

And as I researched, there is no way, to manipulate the computed properties. Of course the example does not work, because in an order there is only the productId.

Comment: ***It is kind of complicated, because in my components I am loading the data via the computed property*** - the computed property ***should know nothing*** about how the order data is obtained, that should be the job of the Vuex action. Why are you not fetching product inside `setOrderById`? If your question is about how to structure state, then you should have separate state for `orderAndProductDetails` with those properties used on the view (currentOrder.product.price) filled in by the action.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to implement this with best practises and build with clean way dynamic order component check the below:

First we register an action call for the calling the api call to get the order info, we store the response through a mutation and then we expose it through a getter to our component.

In the router file we enable the props true so as to get the `orderId` in the component and with that info we do the api call and then we build the component.

I hope I answered your question, if not pls do let me know.
note:do not copy paste the router code just grab the needed code and adjust it to your needs

store file:

```
ACTIONS:

/* Get Order */
  GetOrder: ({ commit, dispatch }, orderId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios
        .get(`myapi/${orderId}`)
        .then((response) => {
          commit("SET_ORDER", response.data);
          resolve(response);
        })
    });
  }

MUTATION:
  SET_ORDER: (state, payload) => (state.order = payload)

STATE:
  order: null

GETTER:
  order: (state) => state.order
```

index.js(router)

```
{
    path: 'shop/orders/:orderId',
    name: 'Orders',
    component: AddMyComponentNameHere,
    props: (route) => {
      const orderId = Number.parseInt(route.params.orderId);
      return { orderId }
    }
  }
```

**OrderComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="order">
    {{ order.product.title }}
    {{ order.product.price }}
  </div>
</template>

props: {
    orderId: {
      required: true,
      type: Object,
    }
},

mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('shop/orders/', this.orderId)
  },
order() {
      return this.$store.getters.order;
    },
```

**UPDATE**
I assume that you have alrdy  in a getter the products.

When the api call is finished, I find order's product id in the list products and when i find it i save it to the `order` and then i build the template. (You will need to adjust the key naming and probably any structure)

```
    computed:{return this.$store.getters.products},
 mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch('shop/orders/', this.orderId).then(()=> this.order = this.products.find(product => product.id === this.order.productId); )
      },
data() {
    return {
      myProduct: null
}
}

  <template>
      <div v-if="order">
        {{ order.product.title }}
        {{ order.product.price }}
      </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think this does not quite answer my question. Getting the data of order already works, but it ONLY contains the ID of the product, but not e.g. `product.title`  or `product.price` because these are coming from another api. The question is how can I connect both, so that {{ order.product.title }} prints the productTitle of the order?

Comment: I updated my comment, pls check it. I believe the logic is there, but let me know anything you might need :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mounted() you want to use beforeMount(). [Details Here](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#beforemount)

> Called right before the mounting begins: the render function is about to be called for the first time.

```
async beforeMount() {
   await this.$store.dispatch('shop/orders/setOrderById', this.$route.params.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not really answer my question. Is my question unclear?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a logical error. If you are representing orders in order pages, you must fetch related product data to populate your store. But you can do this lazily.

```
<template>
  <div v-if="currentOrder">
    {{ currentOrder.product.title }} <!-- UNDEFINED -->
    {{ currentOrder.product.price }} <!-- UNDEFINED -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: "OrderDetail",
  data() {
    return {
      orderId: this.$route.params.id,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      currentOrder: 'shop/orders/order'
    })
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('shop/orders/setOrderById', this.orderId);
    // Product check
    const hasNotProduct = !(this.currentOrder && this.currentOrder.product);
    if(hasNotProduct) {
     this.$store.dispatch('some/store/action/fetchProduct', this.orderId)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

// some/store/action.js

```
fetchProductByOrderId({commit, dispatch}, orderId) {
  //fetchProduct By OrderId
  // dispatch action to merge product data and order data if your backend supported.
}
```

Also there is another option. You can fetch order and product together in action. But it solution comes with performance issues. I hope it will be guide you

Thanks